# jq - select and filter only certain objects from the array

Tags: json, select, jq

My JSON file has the following structure

```
[
    {
        "Header": {
            "Tenant": "T1"
        },
        "Body": [
            {
                "agentTechnologyType": "JAVA",
                "entityId": "SERVICE-EDA448F07EDBDAA6",
                "serviceType": "WebRequest",
                "webServerName": "www.example.com:443"
            },
            {
                "agentTechnologyType": "TOMCAT",
                "entityId": "SERVICE-728B1FF49D132C89",
                "serviceType": "WebRequest",
                "webServerName": "www.example.com:80"
            },
            {
                "agentTechnologyType": "JAVA",
                "entityId": "SERVICE-42A0FB8666B36EB4",
                "serviceType": "Process"
            },
            {
                "agentTechnologyType": "APACHE",
                "serviceType": "WebRequest",
                "webServerName": "www.example.com:443"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I need to apply several filters and leave in the `.Body[]` array objects according to different criteria:

1. Only select these objects in the `.Body[]` array which *do not* have `.webServerName` key present - this condition should leave only the object #2 inside the `.Body[]` array
2. Only select these objects in the `.Body[]` array  where `.webServerName` value is `www.example.com:443` - that should leave objects # 0,3.
3. Select all objects which have `.webServerName` key present, so negating the condition #1 - this should leave all object except #2.

For #1 the filter below does the job

```
[.[].Header as $x |  (.[].Body[] | select( (.webServerName == null  ))) as $y | {Tenant: $x, Body: [$y]} ]
```

It gives the following output:

```
[
  {
    "Tenant": {
      "Tenant": "T1"
    },
    "Body": [
      {
        "agentTechnologyType": "JAVA",
        "entityId": "SERVICE-42A0FB8666B36EB4",
        "serviceType": "Process"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But when I tried to modify the filter for the condition #2

```
[.[].Header as $x |  (.[].Body[] | select( (.webServerName == "www.example.com:443"  ))) as $y | {Tenant: $x, Body: [$y]} ]
```

This gave me the following output - two entries instead of having one.

```
[
  {
    "Tenant": {
      "Tenant": "T1"
    },
    "Body": [
      {
        "agentTechnologyType": "JAVA",
        "entityId": "SERVICE-EDA448F07EDBDAA6",
        "serviceType": "WebRequest",
        "webServerName": "www.example.com:443"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Tenant": {
      "Tenant": "T1"
    },
    "Body": [
      {
        "agentTechnologyType": "APACHE",
        "serviceType": "WebRequest",
        "webServerName": "www.example.com:443"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

While the expected output should look like for case #2:

```
[
  {
    "Tenant": {
      "Tenant": "T1"
    },
    "Body": [
      {
        "agentTechnologyType": "JAVA",
        "entityId": "SERVICE-EDA448F07EDBDAA6",
        "serviceType": "WebRequest",
        "webServerName": "www.example.com:443"
      },
      {
        "agentTechnologyType": "APACHE",
        "serviceType": "WebRequest",
        "webServerName": "www.example.com:443"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And the following for case #3:

```
[
  {
    "Header": {
      "Tenant": "T1"
    },
    "Body": [
      {
        "agentTechnologyType": "JAVA",
        "entityId": "SERVICE-EDA448F07EDBDAA6",
        "serviceType": "WebRequest",
        "webServerName": "www.example.com:443"
      },
      {
        "agentTechnologyType": "TOMCAT",
        "entityId": "SERVICE-728B1FF49D132C89",
        "serviceType": "WebRequest",
        "webServerName": "www.example.com:80"
      },
      {
        "agentTechnologyType": "APACHE",
        "serviceType": "WebRequest",
        "webServerName": "www.example.com:443"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am trying to figure out where I made an error - in the selection condition or in the forming of the new object at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your requirements, it seems you need an expression to select objects  in the `.Body[]` array where `.webServerName` key is `www.example.com:443` or the key basically exists

```
.[].Body |= map(select(.webServerName == "www.example.com:443" or has("webServerName") ))
```

Both your attempts though valid are really convoluted. The standard pattern to selectively filter out objects inside the array is to use the `|=` operator with the right `select` expression.

The `| {Tenant: $x, Body: [$y]}` is wrong, because it is applied to each of the 2 objects you filtered in the previous expression. So each of the result has a `Tenant` field created. Since you have no change in key names (same key `Tenant`), there is really no purpose to re-create new objects with `{..}`.

Comment: Thank you. My question - why ``.webServerName != "www.example.com:443"`` produces the output which includes the object which does not have key ``webServerName``inside?
I understand that I can include additional filter with ``null``, but want to understand the mechanism.